# Generic conversion with Int64

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic method in a MySQL connector witch make generic conversion.
I simplify it for the question, cause it makes lot of things.
At the end, it make a generic conversion and work fine, but I have a problem to convert Int64 to Int32.

```
object var1 = (long)64;
int? var2 = Select<int?>(var1); // ERROR Int32Converter from Int64

public T Select<T>(object value)
{
  return (T)System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T)).ConvertFrom(value);
}
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: What exactly is the error you get?

Comment: Converting Int32Converter impossible from System.Int64.

Answer (score 4):

Can't you use `Convert.ChangeType` instead?

```
int value = Convert.ChangeType(var1, TypeCode.Int32);
```

or

```
int value = Convert.ToInt32(var1);
```

note that these will throw exceptions if `var` is outside the allowable range of `Int32`

Comment: I want to stay generic if possible. Convert.ChangeType(var1, typeof(T)) throw an InvalidCastException ...

Comment: You don't use `typeof(T)` for ChangeType, you specify the TypeCode or one of the explicit functions, which behind-the-scenes uses the `IConvertible` implementation of `Int64`, which is what you want.

Comment: Looks like you're getting confused on the difference between casting & converting. Have a read of http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx to help. TypeConverters (despite their name) don't really support converting using `IConvertible`...

Answer (score 3):

You can't convert from a larger type to a narrower type without an explicit cast.

Comment: And why object var1 = (long)64; int test = Convert.ToInt32(var1); works ?

Comment: Because when using that function, behind the scenes there is an explicit cast being made at some point. If the value is too large for an Int32 to store then an exception is being thrown.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that ChangeType isn't compatible with nullable value types (eg. int?).

If you test for Nullable<T> and then convert to the non-nullable type instead it should work. eg.

```
object var1 = (long)64;
int? var2 = Select<int?>(var1); 

public T Select<T>(object value)
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    if (type.InheritsOrImplements(typeof(Nullable<>)))
        type = type.GetGenericArguments().First();
    // Non-nullable type can be cast as Nullable equivalent
    return (T)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type).ConvertFrom(value);
}
```

BTW... InheritsOrImplements is a handy extension method for Type

```
public static bool InheritsOrImplements(this Type child, Type parent)
{
    if (child == null || parent == null) return false;

    parent = resolveGenericTypeDefinition(parent);
    if (parent.IsAssignableFrom(child)) return true;

    var currentChild = child.IsGenericType ? child.GetGenericTypeDefinition() : child;
    while (currentChild != typeof(object))
{
        if (parent == currentChild || hasAnyInterfaces(parent, currentChild)) return true;
        currentChild = currentChild.BaseType != null && currentChild.BaseType.IsGenericType
            ? currentChild.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() 
            : currentChild.BaseType;

        if (currentChild == null) return false;
    }
return false;
}
```